# Stitch a banner together in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I mocked this up with copy and eraser using this [banners library](http://dragonartz.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/classy-banners-set1/). What Illustrator tool, technique would I use to stitch the pieces of the banner together to create one smooth flowing sheen? In other words, I want to fill in the gaps and connect the pieces together smoothly.[image]

Comment: I would use the pen tool / direct selection tool to connect them together. If you already have them "connected" but they are a separate shape use the pathfinder tool and expand the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the end points and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> on a windows machine) to join them, then alter the points using the point selection tool.

Comment: I can't seem to find an endpoint, only paths, anchors, intersects. I can't seem to select two points I can join.

Comment: Ah - okay. Select the direct selection tool (the white arrow, or press "a" on your keyboard). Then click / click-drag around where the end of the path is. You should now have selected one or two of the anchor points that make up the line. The rest of the path will be highlighted but the other anchor points won't be. If the two end points are close enough you can simply select them at the same time by click-dragging them.